# How do you handle BEM grandchild?

Tags: css, bem

What is better way to write this type of code in BEM convention?

```
<div class="advantages">
  <div class="advantages__container">
    <div class="advantages__title">Title</div>

    <div class="advantages__reviews">
      <div class="advantages__reviews-block">
        <div class="advantages__reviews-title">Reviews block title</div>
        <div class="advantages-reviews-progress">
          <div class="advantages-reviews-progress__title">Progress title</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="advantages">
  <section class="advantages__container">
    <h2 class="advantages__title">Title</h2>

    <div class="advantages-reviews">
      <article class="advantages-reviews__block">
        <h3 class="advantage-reviews__title">Reviews block title</h3>
        <div class="advantages-reviewsProgress">
          <h4 class="advantages-reviewsProgress__title">Progress title</h4>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: should we  create css file for each block ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best BEM is really extensive,  because it's how you make it descriptive. I've would probably just change some minor things:

```
<div class="advantages">
  <div class="advantages__container">
    <div class="advantages__title">Title</div>
    <div class="advantages__reviews">
      <div class="advantages__reviews-block">
        <div class="advantages__reviews-block__title">Reviews block title</div>
        <div class="advantages__reviews-progress">
          <div class="advantages__reviews-progress__title">Progress title</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, if we keep things long, I think better to leave it like .advantages-reviews-progress. So I can keep it in separate file. But still, I feel myself wrong writting such long code